# Is there a "nullsafe operator" in PHP?

Tags: php, operators, chaining, php-8, nullsafe

Is there any way to write the following statement using some kind of [safe navigation operator](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Operators#Operators-SafeNavigationOperator)?

```
echo $data->getMyObject() != null ? $data->getMyObject()->getName() : '';
```

So that it looks like this:

```
echo $data->getMyObject()?->getName();
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

From PHP 8, you are able to use the [null safe operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullsafe_operator) which combined with the null coalescing operator allows you to write code like:

```
echo $data->getMyObject()?->getName() ?? '';
```

By using `?->` instead of `->` the chain of operators is terminated and the result will be null.

The operators that "look inside an object" are considered part of the chain.

- Array access ([])
- Property access (->)
- Nullsafe property access (?->)
- Static property access (::)
- Method call (->)
- Nullsafe method call (?->)
- Static method call (::)

e.g. for the code:

```php
$string = $data?->getObject()->getName() . " after";
```

if $data is null, that code would be equivalent to:

```php
$string = null . " after";
```

As the string concatenation operator is not part of the 'chain' and so isn't short-circuited.

Answer (score 13):

Nullsafe operator allows you to chain the calls avoiding checking whether every part of chain is not null (methods or properties of null variables).

#### PHP 8.0

```
$city = $user?->getAddress()?->city
```

#### Before PHP 8.0

```
$city = null;
if($user !== null) {
    $address = $user->getAddress();
    if($address !== null) {
        $city = $address->city;
    }
}
```

With `null coalescing operator` (it doesn't work with methods):

```
$city = null;
if($user !== null) {
    $city = $user->getAddress()->city ?? null;
}
```

`Nullsafe operator` suppresses errors:

> Warning: Attempt to read property "city" on null in Fatal error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAddress() on null

However it doesn't work with array keys:

```
$user['admin']?->getAddress()?->city //Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

$user = [];
$user['admin']?->getAddress()?->city //Warning: Undefined array key "admin"
```

Comment: I think it's not optimal that it doesn't work with array keys. It's almost intuitive that it should...

Answer (score 7):

No there is not.

The absolute best way to deal with this is to design your objects in a way that they always return a known, good, defined value of a specific type.

For situations where this is absolutely not possible, you'll have to do:

```
$foo = $data->getMyObject();
if ($foo) {
    echo $foo->getName();
}
```

or maybe

```
echo ($foo = $data->getMyObject()) ? $foo->getName() : null;
```

Comment: Okay. At least your second suggestion is a bit shorter than mine.

Comment: I think that this would be a good addition to PHP language. After the ?? operator, something like the ?. operator of C#. So something like this could be written:

`$stringVar = $datetimeobject?->format("Y-m-d")`

Comment: There is an RFC draft for "nullsafe" operator `?->` since December 2014: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullsafe_calls. But it's still a draft.

Comment: @dec you may want to edit this answer as PHP8 has the feature.

Answer (score 2):

For Laravel before **PHP 8.0**, you can use optional()

```
$city = optional(optional($user)->getAddress())->city
```