# Method Chaining based on condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How can you do method chaining based on condition in laravel 4 ? Say if one value is not false then the method inside will be chained to the method called before the if statement.

Is it possible in laravel?

```
$data = User::where('username', $somevariable );

if(isset( $somevar_again ))
{
  $data->where('age', 21);
}
$data->orderBy('reg_date', 'DESC')->get();
return $data->first();
```

// tried code above and its giving me wrong result
in codeigniter I can do this

```
$this->db->select('e.*, v.name_en as v_name_en')
    ->from($this->table_name . ' e, ' . $this->ptc_venues . ' v');
  $this->db->where('e.venue_id_en = v.id'); 

  if(isset($search)){
   $this->db->where('(v.name_en LIKE "%'.$search.'%")');
  }

  $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
  $this->db->order_by('e.added_date_en', 'DESC');
```

Comment: You are calling `get()` which returns all the results and then call `first()` which basically ads a `LIMIT 1` to the generated SQL query and runs it. Why are you calling `->get()` at all?

Comment: Almost relevant page: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12351737/2943403

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe your problem happened because you didn't store back the resulting query after each query builder method call.

```
$query = User::query();

// Checking for username if exists
if (!empty($username)) {
    $query = $query->where('username', $username);
}

// Check for age if exists
if (isset($age)) {
    $query = $query->where('age', $age);
}

// Ordering
$query = $query->orderBy('reg_date', 'DESC');

// Get the first result
// After this call, it is now an Eloquent model
$user = $query->first();

var_dump($user);
```

Answer (score 0):

From Laravel 5.2 and onward, you can utilise [Conditional Clauses/Statements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#conditional-statements):

> Sometimes you may want statements to apply to a query only when
> something else is true. For instance you may only want to apply a
> where statement if a given input value is present on the incoming
> request. You may accomplish this using the `when` method
>
> The `when` method **only executes the given Closure when the first parameter is true. If the first parameter is false, the Closure will not be executed**.

You can use the code as follows:

```
$data = User::where('username', $somevariable)
              ->when( isset($somevar_again), function ($query) {
                      return $query->where('age', 21);
                   })
              ->orderBy('reg_date', 'DESC')
              ->get();
return $data->first();
```

Also, note that [Laravel 5.3+](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#conditional-clauses), it has further been extended as documented below:

> You may pass another Closure as the third parameter to the `when`
> method. **This Closure will execute if the first parameter evaluates as
> false**