# PHP - efficient way to check null object before calling function?

Tags: php

I have this:

```
$itemCode = $area->pickSpecificItemByType($type)->getItemCode();
```

It's possible that `$area->pickSpecificItemByType($type)` might return null. Thus calling `getItemCode()` would be impossible.

What is the cleanest and/or most efficient way to do this?

Is there any better option than this?

```
$itemCode = (!is_null($area->pickSpecificItemByType($type))) ?
     $area->pickSpecificItemByType($type)->getItemCode() : '';
```

Comment: I don't think there is another way

Comment: Could setup a `try catch` and throw an error when `pickSpecificItemByType` returns null. That way it wont progress to the next method. Haven't tested it but in theory it sounds like it should work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than call pickSpecificItemByType() twice, you could do:

```
$item = $area->pickSpecificItemByType($type);
$itemCode = ($item) ? $item->getItemCode() : '';
```

Although another variable is introduced ($item) you gain in terms of readability.

Comment: Instead of just checking if `$item` is returning something evaluating to boolean `true`, it might be better to check `is_object($item) && method_exists($item, 'getItemCode')` to make it completely foolproof.

Answer (score 2):

--- [ edit ] ---

The original reply below was written for PHP 5.*.

For modern PHP (7, 8), please see the null-coalescing operator ?? and (in PHP8) the null-safe ?-> operator

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63222028/773522

---[ original ]---

```
$itemCode = @$area->pickSpecificItemByType($type)->getItemCode();
```

calling getItemCode() would not be impossible, it would just issue a Error.

the '@' control character tells PHP to ignore the warning.  If you get into this warning state, you'll get an empty string (which is what your ternary code was using), so it's a pretty even replacement.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: This seems like a horrible idea, you do not want to suppress error messages because you want to have your "pretty" syntax.

Comment: what is horrible about this is not that it will suppress `the call on null` error, (you're ok with that now), but it will suppress any other error on this line as well and it will die with blank screen of death without any clue for your future-self and you will debug for hours till you uncover the much needed error message consumed by this one unfortunate '@' - trust me, been there

Comment: Theres nothing horrible about this idea. The code in question calls a getter method. Its absolutely safe to say that the only error that can ever be thrown here is the object being null.

Comment: @j4k3 that's not true.

Comment: @j4k3 you cannot guarantee that. Sometimes getters can do other things too. Also it can be e.g. wrong type (if the method declares it).

Answer (score -1):

Would something like this be better?

```
if( empty( $itemCode ) )
{
// $itemCode is empty.
}else{
// Do Something
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below code.

```
$item = pickSpecificItemByType($type);

if( $item == '' )
    {
    // if $itemCode is empty.
    }else{
    // Do the stuff that you wanted to do if $item is not null
     $area->$item->getItemCode();
    }
```

I hope this helps you.