# How to suppress "Call to a member function function() on null" error in laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this code in blade template :

```
{{ $birthday->format('m/d/Y') }}
```

I am getting this error when $birthday is null, how to suppress this exception?

I want to show empty string when $birthday is null, I tried this two solutions but with no success:

```
{{ $birthday->format('m/d/Y') or '' }}
```

And:

```
{{ @$birthday->format('m/d/Y') }}
```

Any suggestions ? I would like blade solution not in eloquent model...

Comment: The cause of this is an old design problem in the engine of PHP. All errors can be converted to exceptions or can be silenced with `@` except when a method is called on a non-object. That case is somehow special. I don't think they will ever fix this.

Comment: @Jonathan ahahah who said that I don't know how to check variable's existence ? Why did you assume ? I am just looking for ideas for elegant solution....In other php template engines exists feature that I am looking for....

Comment: @Jonathan How do you think I solved this issue until now, I used if statement, but my question is if there is any blade feature/solution like in other php templating engines, in smarty templating engine you can use this code : {{ @$birthday->format('m/d/Y') }} . So legit answer to my question is "No, blade can't do this"!!!!!!!!

Comment: I'd like to see how the "smarty" code is different. The rendered output is almost exactly as you see it in blade in your last example. `<?php echo e(@$birthday->format('m/d/Y')); ?>`. Garbage in, garbage out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to extend blade :

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Perform post-registration booting of services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::directive('datetime', function ($expression) {
            if($expression == null){
                return '';
            }else{
                return "<?php echo ($expression)->format('m/d/Y'); ?>";
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use ternary operator:

```
{{ is_null($birthday) ? '' : $birthday->format('m/d/Y') }}
```

Comment: He refuses common sense

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [null coalesce](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) to set a default value for your variables.

```
{{ $var ?? 'default' }}
```

or if you have PHP <7

```
<?php isset($var) ? $var  : 'default'; ?>

{{ $var }}
```

Comment: this : {{ $var ?? 'default' }} is cool, but will not work with {{ $var->someFunction() ?? 'default' }}

Comment: Why would it not work? And I really think function calls should be in the controller and not in the view when possible!

Answer (score 2):

Dates from an `Eloquent` model returns either a `Carbon/Carbon` object or `null` if not set. If you want the date to be an empty string if it doesn't exists you can create an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators).

```
class Foo extends Eloquent {
    public function getBirthdayAttribute() {
        return isset($this->attributes['birthday']) && $this->attributes['birthday'] instanceof \DateTime ? $this->attributes['birthday']->format('m/d/Y') : '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All other answers are way too complex or won't work in case you need to call a function on the variable in question.
Fortunately Laravel has a nice trick for this; you can use `optional` helper:

`{{ optional($birthday)->format('m/d/Y') }}`

It's available since Laravel 6
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-optional

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

{{isset($birthday)? $birthday->format('m/d/Y') : '' }}

Comment: Then I would need to repeat this code 200 and more times:   @if($variable) {{ $variable }} @endif It is not elegant and not DRY valid...

Comment: Don't see where I told you to to use if and endif

Comment: yes true, but it is a one line code. Anyway don't see anything more elegant ... sorry

Comment: ok, in other templating system you can find something like : {{ $birthday->format('m/d/Y') or '' }}

Answer (score 1):

You may construct blade if statements using the `@if`, `@elseif`, `@else`, and `@endif` directives. These directives function identically to their PHP counterparts:

```
  @if($birthday)
    {{ $birthday->format('m/d/Y') }}
   @endif
```

note: using a `@if` in a `@foreach $x` will repeat the if statement for each `$x`
[More about Laravel Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade)

**EDIT**

This is the elegant solution u are looking for

```
{{ $birthday->format('m/d/Y')  ?: '' }}
```

Comment: Then I would need to repeat this code 200 and more times:   @if($variable) {{ $variable }} @endif It is not elegant and not DRY valid...

Comment: Please edit your question with the full code :) so i can observe what u need all i know now is that u need to show $birthday when its value is set. Are u using a blade foreach or a for loop?

Comment: I think question is explained enough. I am looking for soulution how to echo empty string when variable is null...But I am looking for elegant solution....

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 8.0 you can use [`nullsafe operator (?->)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65044601/7082164) and when `$birthday` is null it translates whole expression to null.

```
{{ $birthday?->format('m/d/Y') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

i often use

```
{{ $var->prop ? $var->prop->format('d/m/Y') : '' }}
```