# PHP Method Chaining without writing lots of return this

Tags: php, methods, chaining

I have search about PHP method chaining and all of the tutorial available on the web use the "return $this" for method chaining.

Is there a magic method or library that can be use to help chaining a class method without writing "return $this" at the end of every method.

Comment: No there isnt; unless you use magic invocation which isn't a good idea... what's your problem with a return at the end of each method?

Comment: Might be a new feature in PHP 7.2 (https://wiki.php.net/rfc/pipe-operator)

Comment: @MarkBaker it's I wrote too much return $this on my libraries

Comment: Not really what the pipe operator is about; and it doesn't automagically `return $this` eitherr

Comment: This is a relevant new feature if you are returning `$this` or `null`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12351737/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the language itself there is no way to achieve this without `return $this`. Functions and methods that do not specify a return value will return `null` in PHP as noted in the documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php.

As `null` is not an object with callable methods, an error will be thrown when the next item in the chain is called upon it.

Your IDE might have some features that makes the repetitive task easier to complete, like using snippets or a regex find-and-replace. But outside of that, the language itself presently requires that you design your class to be used fluently with chaining, or specifically design it not to be.

---

**EDIT 1**

I suppose you could conceivably use magic methods to achieve something like this "auto-magically". I would advise against it as it's a poor paradigm, but that doesn't mean you can't make it work.

My thought is that you could us the `__call` magic method to wrap your actual methods (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call).

```
<?php

class Whatever
{
    public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        //If you're using PHP 5.6+ (http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)
        $this->$method(...$parameters);

        //If using < PHP 5.6
        call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $parameters);

        //Always return self
        return $this;
    }

    //Mark methods you want to force chaining on to protected or private to make them inaccessible outside the class, thus forcing the call to go through the __call method
    protected function doFunc($first, $second)
    {
       $this->first = $first;
       $this->second = $second;
    }
}
```

So I do think this is a possibility, but again I do personally think that a magic solution, while valid, gives off a significant code smell and that might make it better to just deal with typing `return $this` where you *intend*, by your design, to allow for chaining.

Comment: If you're aiming for compatibility below 5.6, I recon just to use `array()` over `[]`.

Comment: Good point - the square brackets would throw a fatal on anything less than 5.4. I'll change that over to make the comment accurate.

Comment: I think a snippet is better. I want to avoid future problem when doing unit test, etc

Comment: 100% agree that a snippet is the better approach

Comment: just a small question, If I were to use return $this should I also document the @return on each of my method?

Comment: In your docblock? I think that would be appropriate, for anyone else using your code, your future reference, or for code completion in an IDE. You can use @return self

Comment: Yup, in my docblock. I think so too I should just add it for future reference. Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool like phpstrom and make an live-template for fluent methods where the `return $this;` part already is written. Then use this template via shortcut e.g. fluent. So you will never write a method header,body and return value for a fluent method again.

http://jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/live-templates.html

Have a nice day

Comment: unfortunately I am using Sublime Text