# Is there a null-conditional operator in PHP?

Tags: php, nested, conditional-statements

I want to get the value of a deeply nested property.

e.g.

```
$data->person->name->last_name;
```

The problem is I am not sure if `person` or `name` is declared. I also don't want to use nested `if` statements. `If` statements won't look good for deeply nested properties.

Is there a null-conditional operator in PHP?

**Solved**

There is no need for a `null-conditional` operator since a `null-coalescence` operator does the job.

Comment: empty() http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: @MattiaDinosaur It would still require me to use an `if` statement.

Comment: try this $data->person->name->last_name or 'default' in my case it i sworking;

Comment: Can you do something like this?: `if($data !== null && $data->person !== null && $data->person->name !== null) { echo 'not null'; }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference — What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: @localheinz I am not asking for the symbol. I am asking if there is a null-conditional operator in PHP that will get the deep-nested property.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

php7 Null coalescing operator
[doc](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php)

```
$user = $data->person->name->last_name ?? 'no name';
```

php 5.*

```
$user = !empty($data->person->name->last_name) ? $data->person->name->last_name :'no name';
```

Comment: I noticed that PHP doesn't have `null-conditional` operator since a `null-coalescing` operator does the job. Thanks.

Comment: Please note, that this does **not** work on methods, like a real null-conditional operator would

Comment: Actually, the null-coalescing operator `$result = $value ?? $default;` equals `$result = isset($value) ? $value : $default;` for `empty`, you would have to use `$result = $value ?: $default;` which is a shorthand for ternary operator `$result = $value ? $value : $default;`

Answer (score 9):

There is nullsafe operator since [PHP 8](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullsafe_operator).

```
$last_nam = $data?->person?->name?->last_name;
```

The advantage of nullsafe operator over null coalescing is that the former allows to specify exact parts of the chain that should be null-safe.

Comment: It's also useful if it's a chain of method calls instead of just nested properties.

Comment: This answer is not necessary for this question.  A basic null coalescing operator at the end of the nested property chain will do.  [The canonical for the nullsafe operator is here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12351737/2943403).

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 7, a new feature, null coalescing operator (??) has been introduced. It is used to replace the ternary operation in conjunction with isset() function.

The Null coalescing operator returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise it returns its second operand.

For your example:

$username = isset($data->person->name) ? isset($data->person->last_name) : 'not name';