# Is there a null safe operator for accessing array data?

Tags: php, arrays, optional-chaining

As far as I know, the null safe operator doesn't work on arrays. Is there another way to achieve the same effect with array chaining?

For example:

```
$array = [];

if (isset($array['a'])) {
    if (isset($array['a']['b'])) {
        // run
    }
}
```

becomes:

```
$array<null-safe-oprator>['a']<null-safe-operator>['b'];
```

Googling reveals nothing on the topic.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work on arrays?

Comment: @Barmar I tried it

Comment: There is no such shortcut for arrays, but you can certainly do something like `if( !isset($array['a'], $array['a']['b'])) throw new Exception("Missing value");` rather than nesting multiple `if` blocks.

Comment: You can just do `if(isset($array['a']['b']))`. `isset()` doesn't throw an error if intermediate levels aren't set.

Comment: Depending on the use case (is it an if-statement or variable assignment?) the null coalescing operator might be what you’re looking for. You can have something like `$value = $array['a']['b'] ?? "fallback value";`.

Comment: A clumsy solution is `($array['a']??[])['b']??null)` (clumsy because all the inner steps need to be `??[]` and the last one `??null` also not sure about associativity but parentheses might be necessary)

Comment: What about array nested in objects and there objects nested inside the array?

Comment: @apokryfos The clumsiness is not required at all, the PHP Null Coalescing Operator let you even try to access properties of null directly without triggering an error: `null['a']['b'] ?? null` is valid :)

Answer (score 5):

Null coalescing at the end of array access or object object syntax will work perfectly well without any notices, warnings or errors so long as you are (respectively) only trying to access keys or properties.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZY1M5)) ([the same for both with isset()](https://3v4l.org/EmmTW))

```
var_export($array['does']['not']['exist'] ?? 'nope');
    
echo "\n---\n";

var_export($obj->does->not->exist ?? 'nope');
```

Output:

```
'nope'
---
'nope'
```

Not even mixed access (a path containing keys and properties to a value) are problematic (the behavior remains the same when using `isset()`). ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pAdoF))

```
var_export($obj->does[123]->not->exist[678]['foo'] ?? 'nope');
// nope
```

---

From PHP8.2, for scenarios where you want to use `array_key_exists()` (aka `key_exists()`) or `property_exists()`, you can use null-safe arrows and a null coalescing operator. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pZcDF))

```
var_export(
    key_exists(
        'foo',
        $obj?->does[123]?->not?->exist[678] ?? []
    )
    ? 'yep'
    : 'nope'
);
```

And

```
var_export(
    property_exists(
        $obj?->does[123]?->not?->exist[678] ?? (object) [],
        'foo'
    )
    ? 'yep'
    : 'nope'
);
```

---

The null-safe operator is necessary before chaining a method.

See [Is there a "nullsafe operator" in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12351737/2943403)

If you have a basic class like this:

```
class Test
{
    public function doThing($v) {
        return $v;
    }
}
```

Then you run this code:

```
$object = null;
var_export($object->doThing('foo') ?? 'oops');
```

You will get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function doThing() on null
```

If you instead run this code:

```
$object = null;
var_export($object?->doThing('foo'));
```

You will see that the `doThing()` method will not be reached and `null` will be displayed.

So ultimately, don't use the null-safe operator unless you have methods in your chain.  You'll never need to worry about making a null-safe "chain" with an array because arrays do not offer such functionality to chain functions/methods in that fashion.