# Adding null on blade's option value in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How do I add a null inside this if else statement because it's throwing **Attempt to read property "civil_status_id" on null.** What is the proper ternary operator to use so that it will not throw this kind of error if the  database table has no value yet. I'll provide the code below

**Blade.php file**

```
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group row">
     <label for="step1_civilStatus" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Civil Status</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
      <select class="form-control" type="date" id='civilStatus'   >
      <option>Select Civil Status</option>
      @foreach($statuses as $status)
      @if($status->id > 0)
      @if($user->civil_status_id == $status->id )
       <option value={{$status->id}}  selected>{{$status->complete_name}}</option>                  
      @else
       <option value={{$status->id}}>{{$status->complete_name}}</option>
      @endif
     @endif
    @endforeach
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Check if `$user` is set?

Comment: The **$user** is set already. The problem is, the **$civil_status_id** is still null because the user should pick his/her status after logging in.

Comment: It is not. "_Attempt to read property "civil_status_id" on null_" is saying that you are trying to access a property on _null_

Comment: What is the proper way to write a ternary operator inside that so that it will still work even though the table has no value yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is the part that is troubling you:

```
@if($user->civil_status_id == $status->id )
   <option value={{$status->id}}  selected>{{$status->complete_name}}</option>                  
  @else
   <option value={{$status->id}}>{{$status->complete_name}}</option>
  @endif
```

You can write it as:

```
<option value={{$status->id}}  {{$user?->civil_status_id === $status->id ? 'selected' : ''}}>
    {{$status->complete_name}}
</option>
```

**Attempt to read property "civil_status_id" on null** is telling you, that `$user` is `null` (most likely you have some mistake here...). In this case, `$user?->civil_status_id` ([info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351737/is-there-a-nullsafe-operator-in-php)) returns `null`.