# PHP check if object exists and get it's property in one line

Tags: php, object, error-handling, properties

I am wondering if there is in **php7.3/php7.4** somehow possible to check inline if and object exists and if yes then get it's property like nullsafe operator. Like this it returns error:

```
$object = null;
echo $object->property;
```

But like this it is ok but still too long for me.

```
$object = ['property' => 'success'];   
echo $object->property;
```

I would like to see something like in Javascript `object?.property` but this does not work:

```
//$object = ['property' => 'success'];   
echo $object?->property;
```

Comment: You would need to use PHP 8+ for the last example. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351737/is-there-a-nullsafe-operator-in-php)

Comment: Just use the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to check if it is an object and it has a specific property.

```
$property = ( is_object($object) && isset($object->property) ) ? $object->property: "";
```