# PHP Array if null don't display

Tags: php, arrays

I have the below code in PHP to return values, however if a 'Certificate' doesn't have a second specification (which is optional in the form), I receive an error saying the label is null. Is there a way to remove the second specification if it is null? i'm fairly new to PHP

```
private function returnCertificate(CertificateInterface $certificate, LicenceeInterface $licencee) {
    return [
      'Certificate_ID' => (int) $certificate->id(),
      'Certificate_Licencee' => $licencee->label(),
      'Certificate_Licence_Number' => $certificate->getLicenceNumber(),
      'Certificate_Expiry' => $certificate->getCurrentExpiryDate(),
      'Certificate_Status' => ucfirst($certificate->getLifecycle()),
      'Certificate_Specification' => $certificate->getSpecification()->label(),
      'Certificate_Specification_Second' => $certificate->getSpecification(1)->label(),

    ];
  }
```

Comment: You mean you want to conditionally declare the `Certificate_Specification_Second` element in the returned array?  Please clarify.  We have several pages that demonstrate how to use the spread operator to conditionally add an element.  You may also need the nullsafe property access syntax `?->`.

Comment: Relevant reading: [Is there a "nullsafe operator" in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12351737/2943403)

Comment: I thought you might be looking for something like this: https://3v4l.org/SV7In  I can't confidently offer a solution without better understanding your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much @mickmackusa, i ended up looking at the link you posted and ended up getting it to work with;

```
$specification_second['Certificate_Specification_Second']
  = $certificate->getSpecification(1) ? $certificate->getSpecification(1)->label() : '';
return $certificate_details + $specification_second;
```

Comment: I was hoping to have  a clearer question asked.  So you aren't actually getting an "error"; you are getting a `null` value?  What are the method signatures for `getSpecification()` and `label()`?  Your answer is unconditionally adding the `Certificate_Specification_Second` element ...is that what you actually want?  If so, then you probably want to just use `$certificate?->getSpecification(1)?->label() ?? '',` in your original script.